# String input of weekdays in German to Localdate

Tags: java, locale, localdate, weekday

I have a string input of weekdays in German and need to get the next `Localdate` after today which corresponds to the given weekday string. If for example the input is `Montag` (Monday) I need the output as `Localdate` of `2022-05-16` which is the next Monday after today. If the input was in english I could do something like:

```
String input = "Monday";

LocalDate today       = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextWeekday = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.valueOf(input.toUpperCase())));

System.out.println(nextWeekday);
```

Is there something I can do, may be using `Locale`, to use strings (days) given in German to get the next weekday as a `Localdate`? If possible without defining my own Enum? I would want to avoid doing

```
public enum DayOfWeekGerman {
  MONTAG,
  DIENSTAG,
  MITTWOCH,
  ...
  //methods & getters
}
```

and map them somehow to use the java.time API methods like `Localdate.with...`

Comment: basically you want to parse a string (e.g. `DayOfWeek.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).parse("Montag"))` or similar)

Comment: Doch, you can (and I agree, you should) avoid making your own enum. I would parse the string using a formatter `DateTimeFormatter dowFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN);`. Parsing goes like `DayOfWeek desiredDow = dowFormatter.parse("Montag", DayOfWeek::from);`.  After that you may use `TemporalAdjusters.next()` or `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame()` to adjust your `LocalDate` into the desired day of week. I am probably just fleshing out a bit what @user16320675 has already wisely said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes of java.time are data classes.  They do not have a locale.  They happen to be English names only because the Java language itself is in English.

However, you can make a `Map` for looking up a DayOfWeek value from a name:

```
private static final Map<String, DayOfWeek> germanDaysOfWeek =
    Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values()).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            d -> d.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.GERMAN), d -> d));
```

> {Freitag=FRIDAY, Samstag=SATURDAY, Montag=MONDAY, Mittwoch=WEDNESDAY, Donnerstag=THURSDAY, Dienstag=TUESDAY, Sonntag=SUNDAY}

Perform a lookup on that map.

```
String input = "Montag";

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextWeekday = today.with(
    TemporalAdjusters.next(germanDaysOfWeek.get(input)));
```

See all this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/PEXYcj).

> 2022-05-16

Answer (score 2):

Considering today is `09/May/2022 (Monday)`, you can try :

```
String input = "Montag";
LocalDate today       = LocalDate.now();
DayOfWeek weekday = DayOfWeek.from(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).parse(input));
LocalDate nextWeekday = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(weekday));
System.out.println(nextWeekday);
```

Output:

```
2022-05-16
```

If you execute it on any other day, you might get different output based on day & date.

Comment: The code is working fine (now). On my computer it just gave `2022-05-23`, which is the expected result running on 2022-05-17, a Tuesday.